# How to search multiple fields and calculate each word match once, without duplicate?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to configure Elasticsearch on external data and I am having some problem,
My data looks like so:

```
name: 'foo'
category: 'indie movie'

name: 'foo 2'
category: 'foo 2'
```

So now if I do the following query on the word "foo" in both matches

```
must match name
should match category
```

Would return "foo 2" first, because it will get higher score (since "foo" appears in both name and cateogry).

An alternative I found would be to do "mult_match" queue, with cross_field but then if I will have a 3rd document:

```
name: batz
category: super action movie
```

And someone will search for "foo super action movie" then batz will be the first result.

Is there a way to retreive "foo" first for both "foo super action movie" and "foo"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool.should` with boosting, this worked for me:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "match": {
                "name": {
                  "minimum_should_match": 1,
                  "query": "foo super action movie"
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "foo super action movie",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "category"
            ],
            "operator": "or"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a very hacky solution. But how can Should work as a stand alone in bool query? wouldn't that mean that there will be no filter at all, and it will apply the should for boosting on all the docs in my index?

Comment: If you use `should` without `must` or `filter` it means "document should match at least one of the queries" (if you have `must` or `filter` alongside `should` then all queries in `should` are optional). So you can probably use `{"must": {"multi_match": {...}}, "should": {"bool": {"boost": {...}}}}` here to limit `name` matches. Run a few tests to see which option gives you better relevance.